# different number of lines each time. python

Tags: python

I have a weird observation.
I have a huge text file (it is like 450 MB of text)

I read the number of lines in it.. by something like this.

```
 for i,line in enumerate(f):
    count += 1
 print count
```

In each run, I am getting a different result?
It is not like its very different.
Just that everytime I run it... it is closest to the last one.
For example if on first example it showed 8151, in the next run it shows 8162 and in next run it should 8197??
Any clues??
Is there something I am overlooking.

Comment: What does `wc whateveryourfilenameis` return?

Comment: This seems to indicate the file is changing on disk.

Comment: what do you get if you issue the following command: wc -l <your file> .. is the number your get close to what your program reports? Seems like your file is growing - is it some sort of log file?. Try this with a small text file and see if you get consistent results

Comment: umm.  just executed that.. let me get back to you when it returns something

Comment: what does `lsof | grep <file name>` return?

Comment: wc returns me this .. 8672       8673 4021489664

Comment: I would test your program with a smaller file first.

Comment: @tMC: lsof ... returns this. less      27612      wolverine    4r      REG              253,1 4043706368  17172572

Comment: why the downvote..I read the community guidelines. This is not like a general problem.. THis has a limited scope.. Has a well defined problem and I am guessing there is a pretty good solution/observation for this?

Comment: looks like the user wolverine has the file open with the `less` process. While `less` doesn't make file changes, you likely have something else with a write handle to the file... thats writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have another process with an open write handle to the file that is writing to it.  You can check what other processes have open file handles to that file with `lsof`.

```
lsof | grep <name of file>
```